# Reactance to varying DC

Tags: capacitance, reactance

- Input signal (a) is AC.
- Input signal (b) is varying DC.

As (b) has a frequency but does not change direction, does the capacitor's reactance have a different effect
than input signal (a)?

[image]

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: It's a good question.  Since this is homework, we need to see your effort so that we can guide you. This is not a homework solution site.

Comment: Please advise if this is homework or similar. We are happy to help but or approach varies- with the aim of giving you maximum benefit overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A capacitor's reactance depends only on the value of capacitance and the frequency of the signal presented to it. Your example (b) has the same frequency as example (a), with the addition of a DC component, which has zero frequency. The long term effect of the DC component is to charge the capacitor to 5 volts. After that its reactance would be the same as in example (a). This charging takes place exponentially with time constant RC, so that as a practical matter after 4 or 5 time constants, equilibrium is reached.

Comment: Phil, the commenters under the question were trying to draw the solution out of the OP. This is standard approach to homework questions rather than giving a full answer.

Comment: @Transistor  From the somewhat awkward wording of the OP's question, this did not impress me as a textbook homework problem, but rather a sincere inquiry on the part of a novice

Comment: a sincere inquiry on the part of a novice sums up my position. This was not a textbook homework problem just a want for an explanation.

Comment: @PaddyMak If my explanation satisfies you, please ACCEPT.